# Unable to Use a Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
package com.example.one;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
 TextView txt1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton(){

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);//error line of code
    txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);//error line of code

    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    txt1.setText("hello");
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    return true;
}

}
```

I have marked the error code of lines but unable to resolve 
the .xml is

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:text="Button -MYBUT" />
```

I just want to add a button and a textview in my app beacuse I'm a beginner Android Developer so unable to resolve my issue thanks in advance

Comment: What's in `layout/activity_main.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is a Curse try to not use it guys I Prefer NetBeans I love NetBeans so much Hats off for NetBeans!
The Answer of my own Question:

```
 it was  a real time fault of my eclipse (a curse) not my fault. The Solution is to restart the IDE or to press the Save All from File Menu of IDE
```

Visit:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/7453201/2277645

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know that about the explanation of this line

```
but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
```

`findViewById(Id)` returns a `View` and you have to cast that `View` to whatever UI element you are using.

In order for `findViewById(Id)` to return a View, you have to assign an Id to each UI element (if you want to use it in java):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButtonId" 
    [...]
 />
```

Now you can do this:

```
but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
```

You should also use the `onCreate()` method to initialize your UI elements, and not `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: i have changed the line of code but stil the error is still remain there!

Comment: Did you assign the Id to your button in your XML layout?

Comment: dear I have edited my question and added more details please take a look

Comment: Please save your project and clean it. It seems like the R.java file fails to generate itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `findViewById` after you inflate your menu. You are trying to find an element in a view that has not yet be attached to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is just fine, check your imports. In android are 2 types of R present. 
- R Generated, by your project builder
- R brought by android sdk

I guess that you imported R from android SDK, not generated by your project. That's why eclipse yells with errors at you.

The other situation is, that, the findViewById() method called OnCreateOptionsMenu() callback is trying to reach view that has not been created yet, and returns null.

EDIT. Problems with R might be also associated with weird, not visible and hard to find mistakes in your xml files. When you make huge mistake in some of your xml files, builder returns error and R will not be generated. But in some cases, builder cant find any of your mistakes, but is not generating new R class - this causes your R to be out of date.