# Error in calling of java class in android app development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android development. This is the code I am using:

```
package com.example.databaseread;


import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);

    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Inserting known Languages
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.add(new values("value1"));
            db.add(new values("value2"));
            db.add(new values("value3"));
            db.add(new values("value4"));
            Log.d("Insert", "DataBase Successfully Updated");
        }
    });

    Button but2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Read);

    but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Reading data Already present in the Database
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all data..");
            List<values> val = db.getAllvalues();

            for (values cn : val) {
                String log = "Id: " + cn.getId() + " ,values: "
                        + cn.getValue();
                Log.d("value: ", log);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

The error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - container cannot be resolved or is not a field
    - implements 
     android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick
```

Is coming at  `public void onClick(View v)` line.

I would be glad if anyone could help. Thanks!

Comment: you have written onclick inside another onclick.

Comment: If you remove the `@Override` annotations?

Comment: Check if `Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);` returns null.

Comment: your code seems fine, just try clean-build, check if android,adb, java dependencies are causing problems

Comment: How do I check if Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert); returns null ? @GeorgeD

Comment: post your xml -the layout- activity_main , also try clean-build, [close-open your project, could solve your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527607/eclipse-error-with-android-id-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

Comment: if (but1==null){ //print log info here}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error went away once I cleaned my project and restarted eclipse. No changes were required.

Answer (score 0):

Check the project's properties and verify that Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level is set to 1.6 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onclicklistener {
DatabaseHandler db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);

but1.setOnClickListener(this);

Button but2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Read);

but2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.getID()==R.id.insert){
// Your logic for insert Button
}else if(v.getID()==R.id.Read){
// Your logic for read Button    
}


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}


}
```

Comment: An error comes up at but1.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: an error means how i can understand  . please post the error what you got

Answer (score 0):

Your `setOnclick` should look like this

```
your_button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // your logic
            }
        });



your_button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //your logic
                } 
            });
```

Make sure you have this import statement **import android.view.View.OnClickListener;**

Try changing

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

and

```
but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

to

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

and

```
but2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

Comment: Eclpise gives an error on but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() if I change it.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new 
  OnClickListener(){})

Comment: `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` add this line. You need to import it

Answer (score 0):

Check your id declaration on xml file. It should be as below.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/insert"/>
```

Comment: Changing the id declaration does not help.

Comment: You face the error on the same line or different after changing the id?

Comment: Error is on the same line.